# Getting "variable_name" undeclared error in only one function

Tags: c

I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to diagnose the errors in my code. For some reason, the compiler thinks i have an undeclared variable where its is declared. I am unable to find a solution.

```
struct node {
    int size_chunk_memory;
    //1 = free, 0= used
    int is_free; 
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

void merge(void* address) {
    if (address == 0) {
        return;
    }
    struct node* curr_merge = (struct node*)address;
    struct node* prev_merge = curr_merge->prev;
    struct node* next_merge = curr_merge->next;

    if (curr_merge->is_free == 1 &&  prev_merge->is_free == 1) {
        prev_merge->size_chunk_memory = size_chunk_memory + curr_merge->size_chunk_memory + sizeof(struct node);
        prev_merge->next = curr_merge->next;
        curr_merge = prev_merge;
    }
    if (curr_merge->is_free == 1 && next_merge->is_free == 1) {
        curr_merge->size_chunk_memory = size_chunk_memory + next_merge->size_chunk_memory + sizeof(struct node);
        curr_merge->next = next_merge->next;
    }
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
 ‘size_chunk_memory’ undeclared (first use in this function)
(Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
for each function it appears in.)
```

I have omitted a lot of my program for space reasons. Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `size_chunk_memory` is part of `struct node`. It's complaining about the standalone `size_chunk_memory`. You need a `struct node` object to access it. How do we know if the standalone `size_chunk_memory` belongs to `prev_merge`, `curr_merge`, or some other object? The compiler doesn't know either.

Comment: `prev_merge->size_chunk_memory = size_chunk_memory + ...` here you are using `size_chunk_memory` which is not declared anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prev_merge->size_chunk_memory = `size_chunk_memory` + curr_merge->size_chunk_memory + sizeof(struct node);

curr_merge->size_chunk_memory = `size_chunk_memory` + next_merge->size_chunk_memory + sizeof(struct node);

You access it here outside of a struct reference.  You need to access it the same way the other uses of `size_chunk_memory` do, via a `struct node` pointer and `->`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be on the expression that you are trying to assign: `size_chunk_memory + ...` Not with the structure itself. The struct is just a template to construct and manage sets of data.

`prev_merge->size_chunk_memory` is fine.

It is `size_chunk_memory` which does not appear to be defined in the scope of `merge(void*)`, so the compiler doesn't know what to do with it.